# QGIS coordinates on Emlid RS+ ReachView3

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I am in the UK (Surrey) using Emlid RS+ and ReachView3 to create points for QGIS but cannot get the coordinates to work. Can anyone advise which coordinate system to use on Reachview3 and QGIS?

Comment: "...cannot get the coordinates to work." What have you tried and what happened or didn't happen?